# Direct process contributions

Tags: brightway

I came across the notebook *[Contribution analysis and comparison](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/blob/master/notebooks/Contribution%20analysis%20and%20comparison.ipynb)* which provides a function `print_recursive_calculation`.

```py
def print_recursive_calculation(activity, lcia_method, lca_obj=None, total_score=None, amount=1, level=0, max_level=3, cutoff=1e-2):
    if lca_obj is None:
        lca_obj = bc.LCA({activity: amount}, lcia_method)
        lca_obj.lci()
        lca_obj.lcia()
        total_score = lca_obj.score
    elif total_score is None:
        raise ValueError
    else:
        lca_obj.redo_lcia({activity: amount})
        if abs(lca_obj.score) <= abs(total_score * cutoff):
            return
    print("{}{:4.3f} ({:06.4f}): {:.70}".format("  " * level, lca_obj.score / total_score, lca_obj.score, str(activity)))
    if level < max_level:
        for exc in activity.technosphere():
            print_recursive_calculation(
                activity=exc.input, 
                lcia_method=lcia_method, 
                lca_obj=lca_obj, 
                total_score=total_score, 
                amount=amount * exc['amount'], 
                level=level + 1, 
                max_level=max_level, 
                cutoff=cutoff
            )
```

If I understand correctly, `print_recursive_calculation` returns the activities' contributions (`lca_obj.score`?) including the downstream contributions of other activities. Is it also possible to return only the *direct* contributions of each activity excluding the downstream contributions of other activities? If so, how?

Comment: which version of bwcalc are you using? solutions depend on this

Comment: `pip list` gives `bw2calc 1.8.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have an lca object you can access to the direct impacts of an activity using the `lca.characterized_inventory` matrix. Each column represents an activity in the product system and each row the elementary flows of that activity multiplied by the characterization factors. You can find the column corresponding to the activity you are looking for in the `lca.activity_dict` using the key of the activity as key. So for example:

```
lca = bwc.LCA({act:1},gwp100)
lca.lci()
lca.lcia()
lca.characterized_inventory[:,lca.activity_dict.get(act.key)].sum()
```

will return the *direct* impact of an activity. You can use the same logic to modify the function you posted (which by the way is now part of bw2analyzer).

If you are interested in the direct contributions of each activity in the product system you can also use the following:

```
import bw2analyzer as bwa
ca = bwa.ContributionAnalysis()
ca.annotated_top_processes(lca)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I finally got to try it. I ran the last three lines you posted with `random_act = db_ei381.random()`, `lca = bw2data.LCA({random_act: 1},('ReCiPe Midpoint (H) V1.13', 'water depletion', 'WDP'))`, `ca = bwa.ContributionAnalysis()` and `ca.annotated_top_processes(lca)`. However, the last line returns `AttributeError: 'LCA' object has no attribute 'activity_dict'`.

Comment: you need to run the lca.lci() method to generate the activitiy_dict

Comment: Thank you for your response! Running `lca.lci()` after `lca =` returns `AttributeError: 'LCA' object has no attribute 'characterized_inventory'`. Running `lca = lca.lci()` after `lca =` returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reverse_dict'`.

Comment: Line 1: `import bw2analyzer as bwa`;
Line 2: `ca = bwa.ContributionAnalysis()`;
Line 3; `random_act = db_ei381.random()`;

Line 4: `lca = bw2data.LCA(
    {random_act: 1},
    ('ReCiPe Midpoint (H) V1.13', 'water depletion', 'WDP')
    )`; 

Line 5: `ca.annotated_top_processes(lca.lci())`;

... returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reverse_dict'`

Comment: if ``lca.lci()` returns an error then you cannot get the aggregate score, let alone the contribution analysis. I suggest you open another issue with the exact code you are runnig to understand what is happening. It is strange that lca.lci() returns an error about characterized inventories because to run this python method you don't even need an impact assessment method.

Comment: try running lca.lci() and lca.lcia() as separate lines. not inside the argument for the ca.annotated_top_processes

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I think my problem was that I did not run `lca.lci()` AND `lca.lcia()`. Now `ca.annotated_top_processes(lca)` returns a list containing tuples. Each tuple consists of two floats and one `Activity object`. The two floats are what exactly? The LCI and LCIA? That does not make sense because the numbers are different but with Water Depletion in ReCiPe the characterisation factors are 1 (at least in openLCA). The documentation says `Returns a list of tuples: ``(lca score, supply, activity)``.` `lca score` should be the LCIA and `supply` I guess is the "input"?

Comment: There's still some unclarity for which I will open a new question. Thanks for your support! it's been very helpful indeed!